# TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" - Again

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, npx, npm-start

I use Node.JS workspace with the following structure:

```
root/
    |- build/
    |- ModuleA/
         |- build/
    |- ModuleB/
         |- build/
    |- WebAPI/
         |- build/
         |- server.ts
```

`build` folder contains all the `rollup` output.

root `package.json` has `"type": "module",` which I don't want to remove because I want to use `import`

`tsconfig.json` has:
`"moduleResolution": "node"`
`"esModuleInterop": true`.
`"module": "ES2022"`

When trying to run the web application `npx ts-node ./WebAPI/server.ts`, I bump into the error:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"
```

Running the app with `ts-node-esm src/webapi/server.ts` bumps into the following error:

```
CustomError: Cannot find module '/root/webapi/Presenters/RegisterUserPresenter'
```

on the line of `import`:

```
import { RegisterUserPresenter } from "../Presenters/RegisterUserPresenter"
```

What should I do?

Answer (score -4):

To solve the error, make sure to install the module
and try setting moduleResolution to node in your tsconfig.json file

```
npm install module-name

npm install --save-dev @types/module-name
```

Make sure to replace module-name with the name of the module in your error message.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    //.......
  }
}
```

Comment: It does have `"moduleResolution": "node"`

Comment: `npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fmodule-name - Not found`

Comment: Install latest version of node

Comment: or remove node modules and reinstall node modules type npm install